# CPT theorem and the weak interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, weak-interaction, cpt-symmetry

I am trying the understand how the weak interaction obeys CPT symmetry. My understanding is that, under a CPT transformation, the Lagrangian for the Standard Model should be invariant, and thus the term that dictates the interaction between quarks and the W boson,

$$L = \frac{g}{2\sqrt{2}}(J^{\mu}W^{+}_{\mu}+ J^{\mu}W^{-}_{\mu}),$$
$$J^\mu=\bar{u}^i_L\gamma_{\mu}V^{ij}_{CKM}d_L^i$$
should be invariant under conjugation by $\Theta=\hat{C}\hat{P}\hat{T}.$

However, it is difficult to see that this will invariance will hold using the usual spinor transformations

$$\hat{P}\psi\hat{P}^{-1}=\gamma^0\psi$$
$$\hat{C}\psi\hat{C}^{-1}=C\bar\psi^T$$
$$\hat{T}\psi\hat{T}^{-1}=B\psi.$$

Is it possible to show CPT symmetry using these transformations? If not, why not, and how does CPT symmetry manifest itself otherwise?

Comment: Your QFT text should be demonstrating this explicitly. Certainly Matt Schwartz's text does.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564065/in-this-example-how-can-we-have-cp-conservation-with-c-violation).

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos I can see how CP violation depends on the CKM matrix, but I don’t understand how to show CPT symmetry

Comment: Go to your QFT text and Conjugate the CKM matrix for T: observe the currents. Schwartz does this in great detail.